# Scrape only selected text from tables using Python/Beautiful soup/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and am using beautiful soup for web scraping for a project.

I am hoping to only get parts of the text in a list/dictionary. I started with the following code:

```
url = "http://eng.mizon.co.kr/productlist.asp" 
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table')
```

This helped me parse data into tables and ONE of the items from table looked as below:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="235">
<tr>
<td align="center" height="238"><a href="javascript:fnMoveDetail(7499)" onfocus="this.blur()"><img alt="LL IN ONE SNAIL REPAIR CREAM, SNAIL REPAIR BLEMISH BALM, WATERMAX MOISTURE B.B CREAM, WATERMAX AQUA GEL CREAM, CORRECT COMBO CREAM, GOLD STARFISH ALL IN ONE CREAM, S-VENOM WRINKLE TOX CREAM, BLACK SNAIL ALL IN ONE CREAM, APPLE SMOOTHIE PEELING GEL, REAL SOYBEAN DEEP CLEANSING OIL, COLLAGEN POWER LIFTING CREAM, SNAIL RECOVERY GEL CREAM" border="0" src="http://www.mizon.co.kr/images/upload/product/20150428113514_3.jpg" width="240"/></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" height="43" valign="middle"><a href="javascript:fnMoveDetail(7499)" onfocus="this.blur()"><span class="style3">ENJOY VITAL-UP TIME Lift Up Mask <br/>
                         Volume:25ml</span></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

For each such item in the table, I would like to extract only the following from the last data cell in table above:

1) The four digit number in a href = javascript:fnMoveDetail(7499)

2) Name under class:style3

3) volume under class:style3

The next lines in my code were as follows:

```
df = pd.read_html(str(tables), skiprows={0}, flavor="bs4")[0]
a_links = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'style3'})
stnid_dict = {}
for a_link in a_links:
    cid = ((a_link['href'].split("javascript:fnMoveDetail("))[1].split(")")[0])
    stnid_dict[a_link.text] = cid
```

My objective is to use the numbers to go to individual links and then match the info scraped on this page to each link.
What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `a` tag which contains javascript href as anchor, find all `span` and then get it's `parent` tag.

```
url = "http://eng.mizon.co.kr/productlist.asp" 
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
spans = soup.select('td > a[href*="javascript:fnMoveDetail"] > span')
for span in spans:
    href = span.find_parent('a').get('href').strip('javascript:fnMoveDetail()')
    name, volume = span.get_text(strip=True).split('Volume:')
    print(name, volume, href)
```

out:

```
Dust Clean up Peeling Toner 150ml 8235
Collagen Power Lifting EX Toner 150ml 8067
Collagen Power Lifting EX Emulsion 150ml 8068
Barrier Oil Toner 150ml 8059
Barrier Oil Emulsion 150ml 8060
BLACK CLEAN UP PORE WATER FINISHER 150ml 7650
Vita Lemon Sparkling Toner 150ml 7356
INTENSIVE SKIN BARRIER TONER 150ml 7110
INTENSIVE SKIN BARRIER EMULSION 150ml 7111
```